# R inline code not executing in RMarkdown only when generating HTML through javascript

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, flexdashboard

I am currently building a RMarkdown Flexdashboard and generating HTML code template through javascript. When I generate my HTML my inline R does not seem to work. The code is as such below.

````
```{js, class.source="vis1", results='asis'}
for(i = 1; i < 2; i++){
    $('<p id="vis">`r {1 + 1;}`</p>').insertAfter(".vis1");
}
```
````

I've also tried the following below to no avail.

````
```{js, class.source="vis1", results='asis'}
for(i = 1; i < 2; i++){
    $('<div id="vis">```\n {r} 1 + 1 \n```</div>').insertAfter(".vis1");
}
```
````

This is the output the "test: 2" <- uses inline `r 1 + 1` just to show that it is working otherwise.

[image: Output]

*** I have started to think this may be due to setting results='asis' ***

Answer (score 0):

set i to 0 otherwise it would only run once

```
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    $('<p id="vis">`r {1 + 1;}`</p>').insertAfter(".vis1");
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this just for testing purposes, the inline R problem can be identified in the first iteration

Comment: Can you add the html structure? Do you want to insert the "p" in ".vis1" or after?

Comment: In Rmd ```{js, class.source="vis1"}`` this is creating a <div class="vis1"> and is working fine. It's just the inline R code within the <p> tags that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have inline R code inside a code chunk. In your case, you cannot have inline R code in a `js` code chunk. You can use the `<script>` tag directly, e.g.,

```html
<script>
alert("`r 1 + 1`");
</script>
```